# Django named routes not working with django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to

Tags: django, routes, django-urls

Having an issue with django's named routes. Django keeps raising the NoReverseMatch error when called as follows:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
# tutorials
    url(r'^tutorials/?$', 'redirect_to', {'url':'/tutorials/markers/'}, name='tutorials'),
    (r'^tutorials/markers/?$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'page_tutorials_markers.html'}),
)

# in template:
<a href="{% url tutorials %}">tutorials</a>
```

It looks pretty self-explanatory, yet I can't figure out why this route isn't being recognized as having a named route.

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 1):

Reverse match tends to fail when you have optional characters. How will Django know whether to add the trailing slash or not?

I would recommend you remove the question mark, to enforce that the URLs end in a slash, and rely on the [CommonMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.common) class to add the slashes as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the post. That could be good general advice, however it doesn't change the issue here. I've taken out the question marks on both entries and the issue still exists.